# How to switch to iframe using Id

Tags: webdriver

I am newbie to selenium..

I do have a home page which has create account. If i click Create Account which pops up me to enter Email address and password and submit button.

I have used below one navigate to first iframe.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

It is working perfectly for me.

On click of submit button on iframe 1, there is another iframe which shows me to enter firstName, lastName, gender, and One time passsword.

I am using below snippet to navigate to the iframe and to enter firstName. it is not working

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame("login-iframe");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='fname']")).sendKeys("Test");
```

Can any one tell me is it correct or not?? I have tried setting back to defaultContent and not setting to defaultContent() both..

Source code here:

```
<iframe id="login-iframe" style="width: 800px;height: 530px;">
</iframe></div></div>
<div id="user-verify-modal" class="md-modal md-effect-10">
<div class="md-content">
<!-- a.close(href="#")-->
<div class="tab-links">
    <ul>
        <li data-type="" class="hidden active">
            <a href="#new-wallet"> Complete your details to create XXX Cash Wallet</a>
                <span class="arrow arrow-filled">
                </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="logo pull-right">
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="new-wallet" class="tab-pane active">
        <div class="pull-left border-rt">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="first">
                    <label>First name </label>
                    <input id="fname" type="text" value="" name="fname" maxlength="25"/>
                    <span class="blankfirstName">Enter your First Name</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Last name</label>
                    <input id="lname" type="text" value="" name="lname" maxlength="25"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row radiobuttons">
                <label><input id="male" type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"/>Male</label>
                <label><input id="female" type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"/>Female</label>
            </div>
            <div class="row emailrow"><em class="verified"><i></i>Verified</em>
                <input id="userEmail" type="text" value="" name="userEmail"/>
                <span class="blankemail">Enter your Email where we will send you a verification link once you proceed</span>
                <span class="invalidemail">Enter a valid Email where we will send you a verification link once you proceed</span>
                <span class="invalidEmailEntered">The entered Email is invalid. Please enter a valid Email where we will send you a verification link once you procced.</span>
                <span class="duplicateEmail">We already have a XXX account with this Email. Enter a different Email or Sign in using this.</span>
                <span class="errorEmail">Sorry, there's been an error sending mail.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row changeEmailContent">We have sent a verification link to <b> </b>. Please verify the same once you proceed or <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="changemail">Change Email</a>
            </div>
            <div class="row mobilerow"><em class="verified"><i></i>Verified</em><label>Mobile number </label>
                <input id="userNumber" type="text" value="" name="userNumber" maxlength="10"/>
                <span class="blankNumber">Enter your Mobile</span><span class="invalidNumber">Enter a valid Mobile</span>
                <span class="invalidNumberEntered">The entered Mobile is incorrect, update this to verify the new Mobile</span>
                <span class="duplicateNumber">This Mobile exists in other xXXX accounts. Update this and to verify the new Mobile</span>
                <span class="errorNumber">Sorry, there's been an error sending OTP.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row changeMobileContent">Enter One Time Password (OTP) sent to your Mobile <b> </b> or <a href="javascript:void(0);"    class="changmobile">Change Mobile</a></div><div class="row enterOTP"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sendotp">Resend OTP</a>
                <label>Enter OTP</label>
                <input id="enterOTP" type="text" name="enterOTP" value="" maxlength="6"/>
                <span class="error"></span>
                <span class="otpsent">One Time Password (OTP) has been resent. If you still do not receive the  OTP within 15 minutes, please contact us at <a href="mailto:care@xxx.com">care@xxx.com</a></span>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-bottom:0px;" class="row"><div class="first"><button id="skipVerifyDetails" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Skip</button>
            </div>
            <div><button id="confirmVerifyDetails" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your html source, it looks like `input` with id `fname` is NOT part of `iframe` with name `login-iframe` because it ends and the `input` is below that in the default content.

```
<iframe id="login-iframe" style="width: 800px;height: 530px;">
</iframe>
```

So I think you should search for the input within `defaultContent`. Did you try this?

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='fname']")).sendKeys("Test");
```

On a side note you could use just `By.id` instead of `By.xpath` to find the element since it has id.